# mkmf generates a strange Makefile

Tags: ruby, makefile, travis-ci, mkmf

When I build a gem with native C bindings I get this warning:

```
ld: warning: directory not found for option '-L/Users/travis/.sm/pkg/active/lib'
```

I've found in generated Makefile these lines:

```
CFLAGS   = $(CCDLFLAGS) -O3 -I/Users/travis/.sm/pkg/active/include -fPIC -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 -pipe -std=c99 -Wall -ggdb -O2 $(ARCH_FLAG)
..
ldflags  = -L. -L/Users/travis/.sm/pkg/active/lib -fPIC -Bstatic -fstack-protector -lpthread
```

My system user's name isn't `travis`, neither did I specified that in `extconf.rb`.

Also found this issue: https://github.com/flori/json/issues/207

Comment: Is there a question here other than what that ticket seems to indicate is a "known" bug in one of the makefiles?

Comment: @EtanReisner Question is to determine why mkmf acts like that and to fix this behaviour. The ticket doesn't indicate source of the problem as I'm not using json there.

Comment: What does 'env' say in the shell where you run `mkmf` where it does this?

Comment: `env | grep travis` - nothing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`/Users/travis` actually comes from the pre-compiled ruby that rvm installs, as of around 2.1.0. If you grep for that string in .rvm/rubies/ or your ruby install dir, you'll find it there. I believe the warning is harmless.

If it turns out not to be harmless or you just want to get rid of it, building ruby locally rather than using a precompiled binary should fix it for you.

Comment: On osx it's not benign.  Rails installation fails

Comment: I'm on OSX too. Are you sure this is the cause, and there's not some other error too?

Comment: I got an error during native library compilation complaining about the /Users/travis library path.  I re-installed command line tools and updated and upgraded brew.  Next I got an error about libgmp. So I reinstalled that with brew and the problem disappeared. @nilbus